# I want to move the text so that when I display the image it is to the bottom right of the pane. I'm not exactly sure how to set the position

Tags: javafx

When I run the program, the text appears in the center of the image. I want to move it to the bottom right corner, but nothing happens when I try to change the position. I'm not sure how to set the position of the text.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;

public class Art extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        //this will create a canvas with a width of 400px and height of 200px
        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 400, 250);      
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();


        //draw three ellipses with different colors
        Ellipse e1 = new Ellipse(150, 0, 100, 25);
        e1.setFill(Color.PINK);

        Ellipse e2 = new Ellipse(75, 25, 75, 25);
        e2.setFill(Color.DARKGRAY);

        Ellipse e3 = new Ellipse(0, 50, 40, 25);
        e3.setFill(Color.GRAY);

       /*this will set the color, font and size of the text and place it at the 
        lower right corner*/
       Text t1 = new Text(150, 300, "text");
       t1.setFont(Font.font("Century Gothic", 14));
       t1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

        //display the stage
        pane.getChildren().addAll(e1, e2, e3, t1);  
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }           
}
```

Comment: Yes, the text appears inside the ellipses in the center of the scene. It's not clear to me if you want the ellipses to stay in the center and have only the text appear in the bottom right, or if you want the ellipses with the text inside them, to appear in the bottom right. Maybe you can use some painting software (like Microsoft _Paint_) to draw how you want your GUI to appear and add it to your question.

Comment: Layouts like `StackPane` automatically position their children. If you want to change the position of a child relative to the location the parent places it (i.e. relative to `layoutX` / `layoutY`) then you need to set the `translateX` / `translateY` properties or use a `Translate` transform. However, it will probably be easier to use a combination of layouts that do what you want; hard-coding positions means your UI won't be responsive. Perhaps if you provide a more detailed explanation of what you're after, and clarify what Abra asks about, someone can suggest different options.

Comment: `StackPane.setAlignment(t1, Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);`?

Comment: I wanted to keep the ellipses in the center and move the text.

Comment: Do you mean something like this [image](https://imgur.com/lyR12pB) ?

Comment: @Abra yes exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Slaw suggested in his comment to your question, the below code uses several different layouts to achieve what you want. I suggest you refer to the *javadoc* for details on how they work.

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.NodeOrientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Art extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        StackPane pane = new StackPane();

        // draw three ellipses with different colors
        Ellipse e1 = new Ellipse(150, 0, 100, 25);
        e1.setFill(Color.PINK);

        Ellipse e2 = new Ellipse(75, 25, 75, 25);
        e2.setFill(Color.DARKGRAY);

        Ellipse e3 = new Ellipse(0, 50, 40, 25);
        e3.setFill(Color.GRAY);

        /*
         * this will set the color, font and size of the text and place it at the lower
         * right corner
         */
        Text t1 = new Text(150, 300, "text");
        t1.setFont(Font.font("Century Gothic", 14));
        t1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        FlowPane flow = new FlowPane(t1);
        flow.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        flow.setPadding(new Insets(0.0d, 0.0d, 20.0d, 20.0d));

        // display the stage
        pane.getChildren().addAll(e1, e2, e3);
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(pane);
        root.setBottom(flow);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Another option is what @fabian suggested (i.e. `StackPane.setAlignment(t1, BOTTOM_RIGHT)`), possibly combined with padding or a call to `StackPane.setMargin(t1, ...)`. That solution may be simpler for the OP, depending on what _exactly_ they're trying to do.